# Javascript to change the size of qualtrics text box

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Qualtrics used to have a section of their website called Coder's Corner that had snippets of code that could be used to advance the functionality of the surveys but they did away with that section.

I am looking for the Javascript code that controls the size of a question text box, specifically a constant sum text box. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The answers given don't specifically apply to a Qualtrics constant sum question.  I think the code below is what you are looking for.  Change "75px" to the desired width.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var inputWidth = "75px";
    $(this.questionId).select('.SumInput').each(function(name, index) {
        name.style.width = inputWidth;
    });
    $(this.questionId).select('.SumTotal').each(function(name, index) {
        name.style.width = inputWidth;
    }); 
    $(this.questionId).select('.InputText').each(function(name, index) {
        name.style.width = inputWidth;
    });
});
```

I don't believe the specific code above was ever included on the Qualtrics javascript page. I've made a number of Qualtrics javascripts publicly available at https://gist.github.com/marketinview/

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you are looking to do:

```
function makeBigger(){ 
var txt = document.getelementbyid('txtbox');
txt.style['width'] = '100px';
 }
```

Click [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1334379.aspx?How%20to%20change%20the%20width%20of%20a%20Textbox%20using%20javascript%20) for more info